# Headphones are uncomfortable to wear

Tags: headphones

So I have an Afterglow headset and I use it very frequently. After a while of wearing it though my ears start to hurt and a blister has developed on one of my ears. *How can I make them more comfortable?* The blister developed on the anti helix of the ear (I believe that is what it is called)and I typically wear them 6 hours a day. Here is a picture of the ear cushioning on the headphones.[image]

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your question though?

Comment: Without further information from the author, it doesn't sound like we can answer the user's problem specifically. I'm going to close this as unclear for now, but if you can add more information to the question, please feel free to 'flag' to reopen. Thanks.

Comment: It'd be nice to know in which part of your ear you had the blister, and for how long you are used to wearing them

Comment: Just added where the blister was and how long i wear them

Comment: You mentioned blisters, if you've any heath concerns, try asking at: [Health.SE](http://health.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds as if you're experiencing some kind of dermatological skin reaction, probably to the black material used over the padding. If this is the case, you'd expect a lot of irritation and redness on the skin as well as blistering, and would mean you're hypersensitive to whatever it is, and you need to get new headphones which do not include that material. Otherwise, you could try sticking some other, natural material such as cotton over the padding so it's not in contact with your skin.

There is an alternative possibility though - it could be because the earphones are so tight they're exerting undue pressure on your ears, which would also explain the pain and possibly the blister, where the skin's been rubbed or compressed too much for too long. In which case, you need a new headset which fits more comfortably.